# How to use specify a 'since' value when listing disqus threads with disqusapi module?

Tags: python, disqus

I am using the `disqusapi` Python module to access Disqus' API.  I would like to make use of the `since` argument, to only get the list of threads created since the date I specify.  However, when I pass a value I get nothing back.

```
SECRET_KEY = config.get("disqus-keys", "private")
PUBLIC_KEY = config.get("disqus-keys", "public")    
disqus = DisqusAPI(SECRET_KEY, PUBLIC_KEY)

....

# Ask for all threads since 4 years ago.
t = int(time.time()) - 60*60*24*365*4
results = disqus.threads.list(forum="imaginaryrealities", limit=100, since=t)
print "with since=%d, got %d threads" % (t, len(results))
results = disqus.threads.list(forum="imaginaryrealities", limit=100)
print "with no since, got %d threads" % len(results)
timeseq = list(time.strptime(results[0]["createdAt"], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'))
timeseq.append(0) # offset of date's timezone from UTC.
timeseq = tuple(timeseq)
rt = email.utils.mktime_tz(timeseq) # UTC seconds since the epoch
print "... first thread created at: %s (greater than %d? %s)" % (rt, t, rt > t)
```

Gives the following output:

```
with since=1311988086, got 0 threads
with no since, got 30 threads
... first thread created at: 1437988189 (greater than 1311988086? True)
```

I've even tried converting `1311988086` into the same RFC3339 string that disqus gives it's dates in, and passing that, with the same result.

One of the official [PHP samples](https://github.com/disqus/DISQUS-API-Recipes/blob/master/snippets/php/list-all-threads-between-date-and-now.php) passes in the "seconds since the epoch" value.  The official API "documentation" is [no help whatsoever](https://disqus.com/api/docs/forums/listThreads/).

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting `order='asc'` as well. The `since` parameter is relative to the sort order, so it's looking for anything *older* than that datetime.

Comment: I'll try it out as soon as I get the chance.  It's probably something that should be documented in the API, as it's a somewhat arbitrary limitation.  A query backend like SQL would consider the two things independent.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the time in RFC3339 format along with order = asc.  For example

https://disqus.com/api/3.0/forums/listPosts.json?api_key=[api_key]&forum=[forum]&since=2015-08-10T20:00:00&order=asc

Comment: I mention trying RFC3339 in my question.  Disqus' examples take the integer, so it should also work.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use disqus api *cursor* instead of since parameter. I was getting duplicates when using since (that is, last result of the first query was present in the first result of the second query). It didn't matter whether I added one second to the new timestamp or 30 minutes, it always did that.

*cursor* is a data member of the response body, documentation:

https://disqus.com/api/docs/cursors/

With cursor it works reliably.